# Deleting JSON [ ] Array Element By Id

Tags: php, sql, json, ajax, codeigniter

Project Framework: CodeIgniter

In project, we used 2 tables such as "person" and "emailGroups". We saved people in the "person" table with json_encode by group ID. Because a person can belong to more than one group.

We list people in HTML Table.

```
<table>    
<thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name Surname</th>
                            <th>E-Mail</th>
                            <th>Process</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
    <tr>
                <td>$personName</td>
                <td>$personEmail</td>
                <td><div class=\"custom-control custom-switch switch-lg custom-switch-danger mr-2 mb-1 mt-1\">
                    <input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"custom-control-input toggleState2\" name=\"mailStatus\" data-id='$groupId' data-target=\"$personId\" data-index=\"$baseUrl\" id=\"customSwitch2$personId\" $checked>
                           <label class=\"custom-control-label\" for=\"customSwitch2$personId\">
                                  <span class=\"switch-text-left\">Remove</span>
                                  <span class=\"switch-text-right\">Removed</span>
                           </label>
                     </div>
                </td>
                </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

person table:

[person table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpMGP.jpg)

We have "person" table has a column as "personEmailGroup" includes JSON Contains such as ["1","2","4"]. We want to delete an Id included JSON in personEmailGroup column. For Example we want to delete only "4", before contains Id's ["1","2","4"], after delete shown as ["1","2"] then update.

Delete Function Code:

```
$processToId = $this->input->post("personId"); // person Id who has multiple e-mail groups.
$processToGroupId = $this->input->post("groupId"); // the group Id contains JSON

$getEmailGroup = $this->db->where("(JSON_CONTAINS(person.personEmailGroup,'[\"$processToGroupId\"]')) > ",0)->where("personId", $processToId)->get('person')->row("personEmailGroup");

$getEmailGroup = json_decode($getEmailGroup);
            foreach ($getEmailGroup as $gets) {
                if (in_array($processToGroupId, $getEmailGroup)) {
                    unset($getEmailGroup[$gets]);
                }
            }
            $data = array(
                "personEmailGroup" => json_encode($getEmailGroup),
            );
            $process = $this->db->where("personId", $processToId)->update("person", $data);

            if ($process) {

                $dataJson['status'] = true;
                echo json_encode($dataJson);

            } else {

                $dataJson['status'] = false;
                echo json_encode($dataJson);

            }
```

This code is unwork. Maybe it gives any idea about what we want? We need get new ideas about this process with working code.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have only array of elements, [`unset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) by value is not working. You should use `unset` by element index - . So you need to find the element index and then call the unset function.
Here is your code updated.

```
$processToId = $this->input->post("personId"); // person Id who has multiple e-mail groups.
$processToGroupId = $this->input->post("groupId"); // the group Id contains JSON

$getEmailGroup = $this->db->where("personId", $processToId)->get('person')->row("personEmailGroup");

$getEmailGroup = json_decode($getEmailGroup);

// remove group if exist
if (($key = array_search($processToGroupId, $getEmailGroup)) !== false) {
    unset($getEmailGroup[$key]);
}

$data = array(
    "personEmailGroup" => json_encode($getEmailGroup),
);
$process = $this->db->where("personId", $processToId)->update("person", $data);

if ($process) {
    $dataJson['status'] = true;
    echo json_encode($dataJson);
} else {
    $dataJson['status'] = false;
    echo json_encode($dataJson);
}
```

Comment: It works correctly.